# Checking Linux Kernel Debugging option

Tags: linux-kernel, systemtap

How can I know if the standard kernel provided in my linux flavour has got DEBUG KERNEL ENABLED flags selected or not ??

**I think DEBUG option should be enabled inorder to use tools like kprobe, systemtap ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out how your kernel was configured, check in the `/boot/` directory.  Depending on how your distro does things, there might be a `config-*` file, which shows the kernel configuration options that were used to build the kernel.  Look for the debug settings (eg `CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL`).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the kernel has the "provide config via proc" you can check the configuration of the running kernel by looking at /proc/config.gz

```
gunzip -c /proc/config.gz | less
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's RHEL / CentOS / Fedora:

Kernel configuration is inside the **kernel-devel** package.

The specific configuration used by Red Hat to build your distro's kernel is stored in **/usr/src/kernels/*version*/.config**.

Answer (score 1):

In RHEL 5 you can also check all the drivers that are installed into server via the kernel by:

```
gunzip -c  /boot/symvers-2.6.18-274.3.1.el5.gz | less
```

Note, you can get the full path by:

```
rpm -ql kernel | grep -i symver*
```

Also `lsmod | more` should do as well. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The standard kernel would probably NOT have been compiled with those flags enabled, since this would increase the size of the kernel. The overhead would be a disadvantage to most users.

You always have the option of recompiling your own custom version of the kernel, in which case *you may select your own set of options*.

You can list the modules compiled into the kernel with the `lsmod` command.

Comment: `lsmod` lists modules currently loaded into the kernel.  this includes modules compiled as dynamically-loaded modules.

Comment: So inorder to debug the kernel I should again build a new kernel with all kernel debugging flags enabled ?? Is there any other way to enable them ??

Comment: @codingfreak,
I dont think any other way to get kernel debugging flag enabled.
You must rebuild the kernel if it does not have debugging options enabled.